# When activating OLEControl in my PowerBuilder application, toolbar items disappear

Tags: activex, com-interop, ole, powerbuilder

I have created a COM Interop Control in C# to use in my PB application. If I add an ole control to my userobject and select my C# object in the painter, then an **olecustomcontrol** is created and everything works as expected. However, in order to use a 64-bit version of my object when building the project for a 64-bit platform (in PB Classic 12.6) I added an ole control but hit cancel when asked to select an object, so an **olecontrol** is created and I can use InsertClass to select my object at runtime. This is working for me but I have one issue: when the user clicks in my control, activating it, the toolbar icons on my MDI window disappear. From the research I have done, it sounds like PB may expect the ole object to provide the menus and toolbars, but my PB menu items are unaffected, it is just the toolbar. My control does contain a toolbar (the control is a rich text editor I created to workaround some shortcomings of the built in control) but I have also tried creating a new Interop Control with only a plain text box on it and got the same results. Actually I also tried using one of the Microsoft controls (Microsoft InkEdit Control) installed on my system, and again got the same results.

Does anyone know how I can fix this toolbar problem? (I'm at a loss, but I'm guessing it may be that I need to somehow tell PB to ignore OLE toolbars and/or tell my C# object not to advertise a toolbar.)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, that legacy code we have to support for decades...

The following would take some research and may not eventually solve the problem, but I'd give it a try. I'd implement a "proxy" COM object that'd serve as an extra layer between your .NET OLE control and its OLE container. Such object would be exposed as OLE control to the PB runtime, and as OLE Container to the .NET control, and forward the COM methods calls between the two. It'd be much easier to code this layer with C++/ATL, but it should be doable with bare C#, too.

Then I'd watch the calls made on `IOleInPlaceFrame` and `IOleInPlaceUIWindow` interfaces and block those which lead to the undesired toolbar behavior (if any). I'd also limit the set of OLE control interfaces exposed to the PB runtime to some bare minimum.

The implementation details of [`AxHost`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/AxHost.cs,f2013b75c9b9a9d8) and [`Control`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,9884211b7ff61817) classes might be helpful here, as well as the ATL library source code.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like this may give me something to go on.  I'm busy with other projects this week but will look into this when I have time.

Comment: @Dan, I had some success with this approach in the past when I needed to host a .NET control inside a legacy Borland C++ Builder application. I was dealing with a different issue though, related to the keyboad and focus behavior.

Comment: Well my next problem is VS won't let me create the C++/ATL project, It just says cannot create project.  Apparently other people have had a similar issue where they can't create C++ projects, but none of the solutions worked.  Anyway I'm trying to figure out how to do this in C# (or another language) but I'm having trouble finding a place to start.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Dan, no issues here creating an empty C++ ATL project with a fresh VS2015 install, so can't comment on that. Besides the links at the end of my post, I can't think of anything I'd recommend as a base for a C# implementation.

Comment: I still haven't had any luck with this, but I am going to have a coworker create a blank ATL project and send it to me and hopefully I will be able to open it and create a wrapper.  Thanks again for the lead, I will post my results.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bug. I created a very simple application that retrieves data into ole control and there was no code in any menu items. As soon data is fetched and ole control gets focus the main MDI toolbar disappear. Somebody should report that bug to SAP.

https://answers.sap.com/questions/300798/toolbar-disappear-when-ole-control-get-focus.html