# COM / ActiveX control in 64 bit PowerBuilder application

Tags: 64-bit, activex, com-interop, powerbuilder

I have a .NET control that I have created in Visual Studio and built for "Any CPU" and am trying to use in a PowerBuilder Classic 12.6 application.  In PowerBuilder I choose Insert>Control>OLE and then select my control on the Insert Control tab, and everything works fine - that is within the IDE or when built as a 32 bit application.  The problem in when the application is built in 64 bit mode, the control does not load, it just displays as a blank white box and when the code tries to access it, it throws errors like "Error accessing external object [function/property x]".

I have registered the control using both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of regasm, and I even tried building a 64 bit only version of the control to see if that would work in the 64 bit application.  Finally I figured out I could create an empty olecontrol in PB and call InsertClass to insert my object at runtime, and this works in both the 32 and 64 bit applications (when I register the control for both), however this is not the "standard" method of using ActiveX controls, and there are many strange display quirks related to doing this (one of which is described in the question I linked to below).  So far I have been able to handle most of the things that come up, but as more issues keep coming up, I would really like to go back to the standard, quirk-free, ActiveX method if possible.

The fact that InsertClass works to find the object at runtime, but inserting an ActiveX control at design time doesn't work for my 64 bit application, seems to indicate to me that the 32 bit PB IDE is binding specifically to the 32 bit version of the control.

Does anyone have any experience or thought on creating a .NET COM Control and using it as an ActiveX control in a 64 bit application?

Here is a previous question I wrote explaining a little more about how I am doing this, and one of the many "quirks" I have run into: 
[When activating OLEControl in my PowerBuilder application, toolbar items disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392507/when-activating-olecontrol-in-my-powerbuilder-application-toolbar-items-disappe)

Comment: "I get errors" does not help us help you.  The unobvious thing you have to do is register the [ComVisible] component *twice*.  Once with the 32-bit version of Regasm.exe (or the IDE), *again* with the 64-bit version of Regasm.exe.  This ensures that both the 32-bit and the 64-bit view of the registry has the required keys.  Building as AnyCPU ensures it works in both flavors.

Comment: What version of PowerBuilder?  Have you tried building your .Net explicitly for 64Bit?

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I know I hate when people just say they get errors, I should've been more specific.  Errors like "Error accessing external object [function/property x]".  I do suspect it has something to do with registering, and I've tried registering it with both versions of regasm, and I even tried recompiling the control as 64 bit only just to see if that allowed it to work it the 64 bit application.  I've added more info to my question, both for newcomers and because a comment can only be so long. :-)

Comment: @MattBalent It is PB Classic 12.6 and yes, it works fine when I build to 32 bit, but the problem is we promised our clients that a 64 bit version of our application would be available.

Comment: When you build the 64bit app, do you put the .dll in the same folder as the executable?

Comment: @MattBalent Yes I did try that.

Comment: For now what I did was included logic to use the "standard" ActiveX methods (i.e. Inserting the control through the IDE rather than calling InsertClass at runtime) when running in 32 bit mode.  This solves the problem for now since none of our clients are actually using our 64 bit build yet and likely won't for a long time.  Hopefully by the time someone does use the 64 bit build, this won't be an issue anymore!